# alert box pops up with the error during the selection of a radio button

Tags: ajax, jsf, xhtml

We are implementing the functionality where the text box is disabled or enabled a jsf input component depending on value of another input component which is a radio button. The functionality works, but the alert box pops up with the error

```
malformedXML: During update: new:j_idt335 not found
```

When I click on the radio select options

Radio Button Male O   Radio Button Female O
 Input Box Text Field Male [_____] Female [_____]

Upon selection the radio button for Male the Input box for Female is disabled

Upon selection the radio button for Female the Input box for Male is disabled

```
 <ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    template="/src/template.xhtml">
<ui:define name="content">          
    <h:form id="new" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:panelGroup id="id2">
    <p:growl id="growl" sticky="true" showDetail="true" />
    <p:wizard id="newWizard" showNavBar="true" widgetVar="wiz" flowListener="#{SelectMB.handleFlow}">  
            <p:tab id="tab"
                    title="Form">
                <ui:include src="/jsf/formgender.xhtml" />
            </p:tab>
        </p:wizard> 
    </h:panelGroup>
    </h:form>    
</ui:define>
```

```
formgender.xhtml 

<ui:composition xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions"
>

<p:panel id="type" styleClass="panelNoBorder">  
    <p:fieldset toggleable="true"  toggleSpeed="500" 
legend="Info">

        <div class="ui-g">
            <div class="ui-g-1"><p:outputLabel value="genderType" /></div>
            <div class="ui-g-3">
            <p:row>
                <h:selectOneRadio value="#{SelectMB.genderType}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="male" 
  itemLabel="male" />
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="female" 
itemLabel="female" />

                    <f:ajax render="male" />
                    <f:ajax render="female" /> 
                </h:selectOneRadio>
            </p:row>

            </div>
            <div class="ui-g-1"><p:outputLabel value="male" /></div>
            <div class="ui-g-3">
            <p:row>
            <p:inputText id="male" value="#{SelectMB.male}" 
disabled="#{SelectMB.genderType eq 'female'}" />           
            </p:row>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="ui-g">

           <div class="ui-g-1"><p:outputLabel value="female" /></div>
            <div class="ui-g-3">
            <p:row>      
                    <p:inputText id="female"  value="# 
 {SelectMB.femaleList}"   disabled="#{SelectMB.genderType eq 'male'}" 
/>          
            </p:row>
            </div>      
        </div>              
       </p:fieldset>
    </p:panel>
```

```
SelectMB.java

private String genderType;

    public String getgenderType() {
    return genderType;
}
public void setgenderType(String genderType) {
    this.genderType = genderType;
}

private String male;
private String femaleList;

    public String getMale() {
    return male;
}
public void setMale(String male) {
    this.male = male;
}

    public String getFemaleList() {
    return femaleList;
}
public void setFemaleList(String femaleList) {
    this.femaleList = femaleList;
}
```

The functionality works as expected.

Error Message:-

When I click on the radio select options the functionality works as expected but an error message is shown in an alert box.

```
    malformedXML: During update: new:j_idt335 not found
```

Expected Results:-

If the "one" radio button is selected, the text input field of the other option should be disabled.

minimal reproducible example. 
jsf.version 2.0

```
template.xhtml 
<h:form id="new" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
<ui:include src="/jsf/formgender.xhtml" /> </h:form>                

formgender.xhtml 

<h:selectOneRadio value="#{SelectMB.genderType}"> 
<f:selectItem itemValue="male" itemLabel="male" /> 
<f:selectItem itemValue="female" itemLabel="female" />  
<f:ajax render="male" /> <f:ajax render="female" /> 
</h:selectOneRadio> 
<p:inputText id="male" value="#{SelectMB.male}" disabled="#{SelectMB.genderType eq 'female'}" /> 
<p:inputText id="female" value="#{SelectMB.femaleList}" disabled="#{SelectMB.genderType eq 'male'}" />
```

Comment: Please make it a [mcve]. Also see http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info] and provide version info

Comment: Here you go a minimal reproducible example.
jsf.version 2.0 
template.xhtml

 <h:form id="new" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <ui:include src="/jsf/formgender.xhtml" />
 </h:form>

Comment: formgender.xhtml 
 <h:selectOneRadio value="#{SelectMB.genderType}">
     <f:selectItem itemValue="male"  itemLabel="male" />
     <f:selectItem itemValue="female"   itemLabel="female" />    
     <f:ajax render="male" />
     <f:ajax render="female" /> 
 </h:selectOneRadio>

 <p:inputText id="male" value="#{SelectMB.male}" disabled="#{SelectMB.genderType eq 'female'}" />           
 <p:inputText id="female"  value="#{SelectMB.femaleList}"   disabled="#{SelectMB.genderType eq 'male'}" />

Comment: Edit the question please via the edit button below the question: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56674386/edit

Comment: Please, this is not a [mcve]. See the second link I posted in my first comment. Something about templates. And it is in many more ways not a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Try add the both inputs to div and render that div like below

```
<h:selectOneRadio value="#{SelectMB.genderType}"> 
<f:selectItem itemValue="male" itemLabel="male" /> 
<f:selectItem itemValue="female" itemLabel="female" />  
<f:ajax render="input_" /> 
</h:selectOneRadio> 
<h:panelGrid layout="block" id="input_">
<p:inputText id="male" value="#{SelectMB.male}" disabled="#{SelectMB.genderType eq 'female'}" /> 
<p:inputText id="female" value="#{SelectMB.femaleList}" disabled="#{SelectMB.genderType eq 'male'}" />  
</h:panelGrid>
```

Comment: Hello  @Exorcismus Thank you for your answer. Some how it still does not work.

Comment: @liliangarcia does the value get updated in the bean ?

Comment: Probably the div tags are causing the issue, I ran the code with out the div tags. It runs fine.